# Dot net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need a code for running dot net application without installing dot net framework. If not possible, the framework installation process can run on back end of the program execution.

The requirement is, we have to run our dot net code in client machine where client will not install dot net framework in his machine. It should automatically run the .exe file. But without installing framework the application will not run. Can any one help me out. Thanks.

Regards,
Kannan

Comment: How do you expect to run an app that uses .net w/o supplying the runtime???

Comment: @OldProgrammer: Compile to machine code, or embed the entire runtime in the app, I suppose. Neither of which is possible AFAIK.

Comment: You can use a tool like http://spoon.net/studio to compile to actual native code, or some representation.  Sounds like a poor choice to use .NET though if they aren't willing to install the framework.

Comment: Sounds like a mess. If your have been told not to install a framework you application relies on then I would note this as a limitation to your solutions. Could you duplicate code in C++ or is that not possible?

Comment: Sorry it is not possible to duplicate the code in C++. Main thing is, while running our c# program (exe file) from the client end. Client should not come to know the framework installation process. As usual if they run the .exe file. Installation happens on back end or it has to run without framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are apps out there that are known as .NET linkers. These will actually package up the .NET libraries with your app to run without .NET installed at all on the target machine. There are issues with this, because if Microsoft puts out a fix for something in the .NET framework then you would never get that fix. Also since the framework is embedded into your app, the app itself is larger. Plus you do not benefit from the .NET dlls being in memory already since it is embedded into your app.

1. [Salamander .NET Linker](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/)
2. Spoon Studio
3. [SmallestDotNet](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/)

Google for application and download it.

Comment: Thank you. I will try once and let you know.

Comment: While we are trying with the concept of Spoon Studio. We downloaded Studio. But the exe file is not running. It is asking for License Key. If possible can you please give me an outline for running the exe file in Spoon studio without showing any error or license key.